# constraints doesnt keep it in the middle

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

When I add an image and constraint it to remain in the top-half center of the screen; I would like it to work with all iPhones except it doesnt,.the problem is it only works with iPhone 4 portrait and landscape that I have but when I change the iPhone to iPhone 6 it doest stay in the middle, does anyone know why?

Comment: No, you haven't given us any real details. Show code and screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To geta an element in the middle of the screen here are a few tips:

1. Ensure you drag the object in to the middle of the screen (Horizontally). You will notice guideline's appear up the screen.
2. Set the constraints on the item which include 'Set Horizontally in container' & Set a top constraint only (You may want a height wand width also, experiment with this.
3. For an image make sure that you have set your fill property for your application.  (Aspect Fill etc)
4. A good tip to get used to auto layout is to set your view controller to iPhone 4 and design on that (With constraints of course)
5. Auto-Constraints are rubbish, create them yourself!

Comment: Not in the middle of the screen (my bad) in the top middle

Comment: Edit to change the constraints for your needs

Comment: If you want it to stay in top middle as you said, give it vertical space to container & center horizontally in container constraints. also give appropriate height and width constraints.